# How do I prevent my java application from discarding unacknowledged RabbitMQ messages when I stop my program?

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit, rabbitmq-exchange

I wrote a java project that uses RabbitMQ. I am starting my Spring project in debug mode with a breakpoint on the line that says `System.out.println(input);` in `ListenerExample.java`. In another part of the application I send a message to this queue with the following line of code:

`rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(ManagerExample.getTopicExchangeName(), ManagerExample.getRoutingKey(), "test");`

It hits the breakpoint in my IntelliJ window and using the RabbitMQ manager I can see that `queue1` has one unacknowledged message and no other messages. If I stop the program then `queue1` contains no messages and I lose the message (It is not moved into the ready state on the queue). If I introduce dead letter queues or change `AcknowledgementMode` then I still lose the message. How can I retain this message somehow either in another queue or in `queue1`?

ListenerExample.java:

```
package rabbitExample;

import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitListener;
import org.springframework.amqp.support.AmqpHeaders;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Header;

import java.io.IOException;

@Component
public class ListenerExample {
  @RabbitListener(queues = ManagerExample.queueName, containerFactory = "prefetchOneRabbitListenerContainerFactory")
  public static void listen(final String input, final Channel channel, @Header(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG) final long tag) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(input);
    channel.basicAck(tag, false);
  }
}
```

ManagerExample.java:

```
package rabbitExample;

import lombok.Getter;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.AcknowledgeMode;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Binding;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.BindingBuilder;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.QueueBuilder;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.TopicExchange;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.config.SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.RabbitListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ManagerExample {
  @Getter
  static final String topicExchangeName = "exchange";
  @Getter
  static final String queueName = "queue1";
  @Getter
  static final String deadLetterQueueName = "dropped";
  @Getter
  static final String routingKey = "key";

  @Bean
  Queue queue() {
    return QueueBuilder.durable(queueName)
      .build();
  }

  @Bean
  static TopicExchange exchange() {
    return new TopicExchange(topicExchangeName);
  }

  @Bean
  Binding binding(final Queue queue, final TopicExchange exchange) {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(routingKey);
  }

  @Bean
  public RabbitListenerContainerFactory<SimpleMessageListenerContainer> prefetchOneRabbitListenerContainerFactory(final ConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory) {
    final SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(rabbitConnectionFactory);
    factory.setPrefetchCount(1);
    factory.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.MANUAL);
    return factory;
  }
}
```

Comment: The behavior you describe is not what happens; if you kill an app while it has unacknowledged messages, they will be requeued (returned to the ready state). If you can post the complete project someplace, I can take a look to see what's wrong.

Comment: I am now seeing the message get added back to the queue instead of being discarded despite me not changing anything (The next day). I'm glad I know now how it is supposed to behave given the code I posted though.

Comment: @GaryRussell https://github.com/CaptionOption/RabbitMQFailure contains a project that causes the queue to drop messages when I start a RabbitMQ service using docker. Any suggestions for why this would be the case would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to run your example. Everything works fine. An unacked message returned back to the queue without any problems.
You could try to make little change in your "listen" method, for example:

```
  @RabbitListener(queues = RabbitConfig.QUEUE, containerFactory = "prefetchOneRabbitListenerContainerFactory")
  public static void listen(final String input, final Channel channel, @Header(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG) final long tag) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(input);
        System.exit(0);
        channel.basicAck(tag, false);
  }
```

and you will see, that all works fine. I think, original problem in your case is way of "stopping" application. I assume that you click the "Stop" button right in Intellij Idea.
But for unknown reasons Intellij Idea doesn't stop process immediately and `channel.basicAck(tag, false);` command
runs after your pushed "Stop" button.

[Example](https://github.com/volodya-lombrozo/stackoverflow_65620809)

Comment: I have come back to confirm that what you said is correct. Adding `System.exit(0);` causes the message to be returned to the queue and without it the message is dropped.

Comment: Of course, because you have "basicAck" command and it's normal behaviour